# What would happen if the Earth blew up?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

Let's say aliens try to blow up the Earth. Large explosion. Boom! Chunks of planet, hypothetically ranging from small to state sized because I don't know how this works, flying off into space. Is there any chance some of the Earth would remain intact and in it's current trajectory? Or would the whole thing be destroyed and/or knocked off course?

Comment: One question per post, please. And each question with a narrow and well defined scope.

Comment: What do _you_ want? If you start from that premise, everything else can be tweaked to fit.

Comment: Hi Cthulhu, I saw your edit and think you're on the right track to getting this reopened! The main bit of information we'll need to answer this decisively is *how* large of an explosion. Saying "large" when talking about galactic scales could refer to anything from Tsar Bomba to a supernova, with *wildly* different consequences for the planet. I'd recommend [this awesome Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)) for help wrapping your head around the numbers.

Answer (score 4):

1. The people on one of the chunks, how long could they survive?

They'd die instantly. You're talking about blowing up earth. That means any chuck on which humans are needs to be given enough force to be thrown to orbit at least. Because it's caused by explosive, not prolonged event, this means that moment the chunk of earth starts to move, people on it are crushed by suddenly being under effect of hundreds of thousand? millions? billions? g. They're dead before they notice anything weird. Buildings would be flattened, suddenly "weighing" many thousand or millions of time more than they should, for a fraction of second.

2. What would happen to the atmosphere on a chunk? Would it just disappear?

Yeah, your chunk would perhaps push bit of atmosphere with it during explosion, but in matter of seconds, it would be gone.

3. How long would it take for a chunk to get too far away from/too close to the sun before it was too cold/hot for survival?

Till it was sent towards/away from sun, by something. It would just fall apart and orbit sun in form of small chunks.

4. What would the end be like for those people?

Instant death before they noticed anything.

5. Would it even be possible for parts of a side or two to blow off or would it have to be the whole thing?

???

6. If it could be just part of the planet, would it be possible for it to not get knocked out of orbit?

Yeah, you need much more energy to get closer to sun by a big margin than to just leave Earth. Most likely, it would form some eliptic orbit around sun. Though by that time, it would be in form of a cloud of debris, mostly melted debris.

7. What would happen to the planet if just parts blew off? How would the atmosphere be affected? Or the oceans? Could people even survive on what was left?

No. What we're talking about is impact of power at least hundred times worse than asteroid that killed dinosaurs. It's likely all people would be dead within matter of minutes.

Comment: You might want to know that we have a [be nice](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) policy, and that we prefer to answer only well asked questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Blow it up gently**

When you blow up thing with bombs, the energies involved are huge.  Things get red hot.  Atmosphere is stripped away.  Stuff would fly apart and then gravity would pull it crunching back together.   It is a bad set of circumstances for living creatures.

If you want inhabited chunks of Earth flying off into space with atmosphere attached you will need to do it gently.  I am reminded of the scene in Age of Ultron which by some vibranium jiggery-pokery, a small nation was gradually lifted off the surface of the earth. 
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91402/how-did-the-vibranium-lift-sokovia

Your aliens can do something similar.  A gravity poison?  Perhaps this is for an alien art project?  Or perhaps they are gently stripping away the outer layers of the planet to facilitate access to the unobtanium which is in the core?  That would be cool because the humans could watch this happen to Mars before it happens to Earth.

The other thing is if there were some alien mechanisms attached to the chunks of Earth, maybe survivors could hack them and control the trajectory of their chunk to some degree.  An unorthodox spacecraft to be sure but great for a fiction.

Comment: +1 for imaginative alternatives